# Programmaticaly How to find Google Chrome profile directory in MAC OSX where all Histories and bookmarks stores

Tags: macos, osx-lion

According to the Chrome website, the User Data directory should be ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default, but I don't see "Google" under "Application Support".

Does anyone know where else the User Data directory could be?
reference 
https://superuser.com/questions/522722/cant-find-the-google-chrome-user-data-directory-in-mac-osx-lion
I am not getting the Histories by following this tutorial

Comment: /Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/      I am not getting the Google Folder inside Application Support

Comment: /Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default

Answer (score 4):

To get the path, follow the steps below.

In the search bar type the following and press enter

[image]

This will then show all the metadata. There find the path to the profile

[image]

**I presume the same results would also apply other OS, though I haven't tested it.**

Answer (score 0):

First of all - make sure that you look at the right path under the right user.

This explanation was also very useful for me :

https://www.howtogeek.com/255653/how-to-find-your-chrome-profile-folder-on-windows-mac-and-linux/

Second - Maybe it sounds stupid but I had the same problem - didn't see  "Google" under "Application Support".
Apparently - chrome was never been used in my computer (I used Safari) so after I opened it and entered some websites - the "Google" directory was created (under  ~/Library/Application Support/) and I also found the chrome history file I was looking for :)